# how to find detail of person belong to chennai

Tags: mongodb

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59dc5ef861e3f5ed652aaebd"),
"pat_deta" : {
        "pname" : "prabhat",
        "age" : 53,
        "sex" : "male"
},
"pat_death" : {
        "p_d_reason" : "cancer",
        "death_time" : "6:00 AM",
        "death_date" : "01-may-2011",
        "place" : "delhi",
        "country" : "india"
}


"_id" : ObjectId("59dc5f2e61e3f5ed652aaebe"),
"pat_deta" : {
        "pname" : "ankur",
        "age" : 73,
        "sex" : "male"
},
"pat_death" : {
        "p_d_reason" : "typhoid",
        "death_time" : "7:00 AM",
        "death_date" : "01-june-2011",
        "place" : "noida",
        "country" : "india"
}


"_id" : ObjectId("59dc5f7d61e3f5ed652aaebf"),
"pat_deta" : {
        "pname" : "arima",
        "age" : 29,
        "sex" : "female"
},
"pat_death" : {
        "p_d_reason" : "blood cancer",
        "death_time" : "8:00 AM",
        "death_date" : "01-july-2011",
        "place" : "hyderabad",
        "country" : "india"
}


"_id" : ObjectId("59dc5fe261e3f5ed652aaec0"),
"pat_deta" : {
        "pname" : "garima",
        "age" : 39,
        "sex" : "female"
},
"pat_death" : {
        "p_d_reason" : "accident",
        "death_time" : "9:00 AM",
        "death_date" : "01-aug-2011",
        "place" : "chennai",
        "country" : "india"
}
```

how to find detail of a person belong to chennai

Comment: We can simply say `db.collection("dbCollection").find({"pat_death.place": "chennai"})`

Comment: thanks man ....now its working...

Answer (score 0):

`db.collectionname.find({place: "chennai"})`

Replace collectionname with the name of the collection that has the data you listed.

Answer (score 0):

use promise and get the response.Please use this link for better understanding
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp